# Shopware 6 PayPal Invoice Purchase does not include order_transaction custom_fields swag_paypal_pui_payment_instruction on some orders

Tags: paypal, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

We sporadically observe missing data in PayPal purchase on invoice purchase orders. We have a middleware that listen to "state_enter.order_transaction.state.paid" webhook and then forwards the order to an ERP system.

Until now we have received all necessary data in the order_transaction => custom_fields. For invoice purchase the swag_paypal_pui_payment_instruction data are important for us.

```
{
"swag_paypal_order_id": "....", 
"swag_paypal_partner_attribution_id": "shopwareAG_Cart_Shopware6_PPCP", 
"swag_paypal_pui_payment_instruction": {
    "name": {... }, 
    "email": "...", 
    "birth_date": "...", 
    "phone": {...}, 
    "billing_address": {...}, 
    "payment_reference": "...", 
    "deposit_bank_details": {...}, 
    "experience_context": {....}, 
    "swag_paypal_resource_id": "..."
}
```

However, for some orders we do not receive any data in the field: swag_paypal_pui_payment_instruction.

```
{
    "swag_paypal_order_id": "....", 
    "swag_paypal_partner_attribution_id": "shopwareAG_Cart_Shopware6_PPCP"
}
```

But it is not a problem with the webhook or the request, because the data is already not available in the database for this orders.

I find the following error messages in the logs at this date, but for a different transaction, which then has the necessary data at the end. But I cannot find any log entries for the transaction that has no data.

```
[2022-11-27T20:30:10.896943+00:00] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Swag\PayPal\Checkout\PUI\Exception\PaymentInstructionsNotReadyException: "Payment instructions for transaction "b87…….b0c1" not yet available" at /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/prod/custom/plugins/SwagPayPal/src/Checkout/PUI/SalesChannel/PUIPaymentInstructionsRoute.php line 129 {"exception":"[object] (Swag\\PayPal\\Checkout\\PUI\\Exception\\PaymentInstructionsNotReadyException(code: 0): Payment instructions for transaction \" b87…….b0c1\" not yet available at /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/prod/custom/plugins/SwagPayPal/src/Checkout/PUI/SalesChannel/PUIPaymentInstructionsRoute.php:129)"} []
```

Has anyone observed anything similar?

**Shopware Version:  6.4.14.0**

**Paypal Plugin: 5.4.1**

Answer (score 1):

Here is shopwares support answer, it may help someone.

„The behaviour occurs when the customer does not wait for the confirmation from PayPal after the redirection from PayPal back to the shop.“

> Ich hab den Sachverhalt nochmal genau geprüft und nach Rücksprache mit
> der Entwicklung identifizieren können, dass das Verhalten auftritt,
> wenn der Kunde nach der Umleitung von PayPal zum Shop zurück die
> Bestätigung von PayPal nicht abwartet. Dieses Verhalten ist
> entsprechend nicht direkt auf Shopware-Seite beeinflussbar. Die Kunden
> erhalten von RatePay / PayPal eine E-Mail mit der
> Zahlungsaufforderung. In solchen Fällen schreibt Shopware ein
> entsprechenden Hinweis auf die Rechnung anstelle der Kontodetails.

Unfortunately, the reference mentioned does not exist. The last statement is that  Shopware will look into it.

> ich habe mich noch mal Rücksprache mit der Entwicklung gehalten. Die
> Meldung auf der Rechnung erscheint nur, wenn der Zahlvorgang auch
> funktioniert hat. Wir schauen uns für zukünftige Updates an, ob sich
> das noch anders lösen lässt. In jedem Fall, also egal ob der Kunde die
> Bestätigung von PayPal abwartet oder nicht abwartet wird eine Mail von
> Ratepay mit den Zahlungsinformationen versendet.

I hope that it will be possible to solve this better in the future so that the necessary data can be transferred cleanly to other systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the PayPal plugin but just from looking at the code I found two instances where the custom field is written.

[`PlusPuiHandler`](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/blob/6a0547459dff3916c9cf13a5490325f52e622f09/src/Checkout/Payment/Handler/PlusPuiHandler.php#L342), [`PayPalPuiPaymentHandler`](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/blob/6a0547459dff3916c9cf13a5490325f52e622f09/src/Checkout/Payment/PayPalPuiPaymentHandler.php#L188)

In both cases the custom field is explicitly not written if the instruction type is not invoice or if the payment instructions are `null`. Since you mentioned this specifically regards invoice payments, there's only one place I could find where instructions are set.

[`PUIPaymentInstructionDataService`](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/blob/6a0547459dff3916c9cf13a5490325f52e622f09/src/Checkout/PUI/Service/PUIPaymentInstructionDataService.php#L57)

There's potentially a `PaymentInstructionsNotReadyException` being thrown here. So it looks like you were on the right track. The exception is also deliberately being caught with the intention of "polling it later", even though I'm not quite sure what that means. Maybe you could try and repeat the call used for the argument of `setPaymentInstructions` and get the instructions at a later point?

Comment: I exported all rows from the order_transaction table with the payment_method_id E00199FB0F89424DBAD70EEE164C3FFF which are the invoice purchase transactions out of 953 transactions 25 are missing the swag_paypal_pui_payment_instruction data.
All of these 25 transactions went through successfully. This is a problem with the plugin, isn't it?
How can I subsequently request the payment instructions from the plugin, especially if the transaction was successful?

Comment: The exception is only thrown [if the status of the order resource received from PayPal is not `COMPLETED` at the time](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/blob/22e5740522a56b5d6854efe073eeb3da4796f406/src/Checkout/PUI/SalesChannel/PUIPaymentInstructionsRoute.php#L129). That status is received via the PayPal API on the spot, so the question would be why PayPal deemed that small number of orders incomplete at the time. Unfortunately I don't have an answer to that. I'd recommend keeping and eye out for that exception. Try to find things that orders missing the field have in common.